# Is there a way I can bundle a jre in a Launch4j .exe file?

Tags: java, maven, exe, launch4j

I would like to bundle a jre folder into my generated launch4j .exe file via maven pom.xml (For some reason, I don't want an installer, just a click to run Java application that has its own embedded jre). Is it possible? I have read through several posts and I don't get a maven automated one. I don't want to do it the manual way, just by packaging through maven because of some reasons

I've tried bundling a jre folder into an exe file via maven but it ends up not running after I uninstall java from my system or after I remove the jre folder from which the pom.xml Launch4j configuration was using . Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I found a perfect tool for just the above task, **[Warp-Packer](https://github.com/dgiagio/warp)**. The software just requires a few CMD commands/terminal commands to compress and add your JRE and pre-generated executable(from software like Launch4j or any of your preference) to one .EXE file which requires no installation. Click to run.

Basically, it is a simple command like:

`cd %jre_folder%`  - **%jre_folder%** is the path to your folder where the **warp-packer.exe**, **JRE** and **pre-generated exe**(in my case **myapp.exe**) file are.
then type the following:

```
.\warp-`packer` --arch windows-x64 --input_dir jre_folder --exec myapp.exe --output myapp.exe
```

The image below illustrates that

[image: Check this example]

Comment: Nice! Did you find a way to set an icon from the warp-packer?

Comment: @NotArchon Unfortunately, Warp-packer does not provide a way to set up an exe icon. You can check out Resource Hacker, it might be of help to your needs

Comment: I used warp-packer to pack folder called jre11 and MyApp.jar... runs fine but a terminal always shows for a moment when the exe is ran... have you experienced this?

Comment: Yes, I did experience it. I think that is the disadvantage that comes with its suitability for that job